# How to correctly format NURBS curves for wavefront .OBJ file format?

Tags: graphics, .obj, wavefront, bspline, nurbs

I am trying to write a [wavefront .OBJ file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) that contains 3D [NURBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline)  curves (not surfaces). I found the following link that describes how to correctly format curves and surfaces within .OBJ files: http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec

There is no example for a rational b-spline curve, and it's not clear to me from the documentation how the knot vector is formatted within the `parm u` section. Any help would be appreciated.

Examples of related code follow. At the link above, there is a description of a rational b-spline surface:

```
v -1.3 -1.0  0.0
v  0.1 -1.0  0.4  7.6
v  1.4 -1.0  0.0  2.3
v -1.4  0.0  0.2
v  0.1  0.0  0.9  0.5
v  1.3  0.0  0.4  1.5
v -1.4  1.0  0.0  2.3
v  0.1  1.0  0.3  6.1
v  1.1  1.0  0.0  3.3
vt 0.0  0.0
vt 0.5  0.0
vt 1.0  0.0
vt 0.0  0.5
vt 0.5  0.5
vt 1.0  0.5
vt 0.0  1.0
vt 0.5  1.0
vt 1.0  1.0
cstype rat bspline
deg 2 2
surf 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1/1 2/2 3/3 4/4 5/5 6/6 \
7/7 8/8 9/9
parm u 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
parm v 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
end
```

and another example for a bezier curve:

```
v -2.300000 1.950000 0.000000
v -2.200000 0.790000 0.000000
v -2.340000 -1.510000 0.000000
v -1.530000 -1.490000 0.000000
v -0.720000 -1.470000 0.000000
v -0.780000 0.230000 0.000000
v 0.070000 0.250000 0.000000
v 0.920000 0.270000 0.000000
v 0.800000 -1.610000 0.000000
v 1.620000 -1.590000 0.000000
v 2.440000 -1.570000 0.000000
v 2.690000 0.670000 0.000000
v 2.900000 1.980000 0.000000
# 13 vertices

cstype bezier
ctech cparm 1.000000
deg 3
curv 0.000000 4.000000 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 \
11 12 13
parm u 0.000000 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000  \
4.000000
end
# 1 element
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to store the information of a NURBS curve in the wavefront .obj file.

Here is one example:

```
v -2.300000 1.950000 1.000000 1.000000 
v -2.200000 0.790000 2.000000 1.000000 
v -2.340000 -1.510000 0.000000 1.000000 
v -1.530000 -1.490000 0.000000 1.000000 
v -0.720000 -1.470000 0.000000 1.000000 
v -0.780000 0.230000 0.000000 1.000000 

cstype rat bspline
deg 2
curv 0.00 1.00 1 2 3 4 5 6 
parm u 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00 1.00 1.00  
end
```

Now let's have a closer look. We have 6 vertices in cartesian coordinates with additional weight coordinate (x, y, z, w). To define a rational b-spline (NURBS) with a degree of 2 we have to set

```
cstype rat bspline
deg 2
```

The next values are defining the curv. The syntax is:

```
curv [u-start] [u-end] [first-cp] [second-cp] [...]
```

http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec, line 788:

> curv u0 u1 v1 v2 . . .
>
> Element statement for free-form geometry.
>
> Specifies a curve, its parameter range, and its control vertices.
>   Although curves cannot be shaded or rendered, they are used by other
>   Advanced Visualizer programs.
>
> u0 is the starting parameter value for the curve. This is a floating
>   point number.
>
> u1 is the ending parameter value for the curve. This is a floating
>   point number.
>
> v is the vertex reference number for a control point. You can specify
>   multiple control points. A minimum of two control points are required
>   for a curve.
>
> For a non-rational curve, the control points must be 3D. For a
>   rational curve, the control points are 3D or 4D. The fourth coordinate
>   (weight) defaults to 1.0 if omitted.

Now we define the u vector/sequence. The values are of course depending on your geometry.

```
parm u [knot1] [knot2] [...]
```

http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec, line 1107:

> parm u p1 p2 p3. . .
>
> parm v p1 p2 p3 . . .
>
> Body statement for free-form geometry.
>
> Specifies global parameter values. For B-spline curves and surfaces,
>   this specifies the knot vectors.
>
> u is the u direction for the parameter values.
>
> v is the v direction for the parameter values.
>
> To set u and v values, use separate command lines.
>
> p is the global parameter or knot value. You can specify multiple
>   values. A minimum of two parameter values are required. Parameter
>   values must increase monotonically. The type of surface and the degree
>   dictate the number of values required.

I hope this helps!